# How to create a branch in a git repository right from GitBash prompt?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I was looking for a command that can be used from GitBash command line to create a branch in my git repository. I can do that from the online git repository but I want to do it locally on my machine from GitBash prompt.

Comment: I suggest you read [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). It shows you exactly how to do this. The first three chapters explain all the fundamental git commands

Comment: `git branch ...`?

Comment: Just type `git branch some_branch`.  Or, to create a new branch and check it out at the same time, use `git checkout -b some_branch`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, *every* git manual shows you how to do this. Many of them start with it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist And I gave a link to my favorite one.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Thanks for the link. I never knew it was called Pro Git. I tagged you in my comment but I meant it for OP. Sorry, it was late and made sense at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to create a new branch with name = branch_name

```
git branch branch_name
```

And to use move to that branch use :

```
git checkout branch_name
```

You could also create a new branch and switch to it in a single operation:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

For more information, have a look at the Git manual on branching and merging:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

This is a good place for a beginner to start learning about Git.

Comment: You don't really need to answer this question.  It's a duplicate of so many other SO questions.